# How do I make a clan?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-ghosts

When I create a clan in the multiplayer menu, it says clan created but I cannot add or invite people to my clan.
I go to create a new one assuming the request was canceled or not entered correctly, it says clan name already exists as if someone else created it.

Is this a bug?
Did I do it wrong?
Or am I missing something?

I'm on the PS3.
Will this also happen on my Xbox 360 Version?

Comment: What was the clan name? I can check to see if it has truly been created and if you're the only member for you if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the COD app. The Call of Duty app lets you keep track of your multiplayer progress and awards using your mobile devices. The Call of Duty app is available for iPhones/iPads, Android, and Windows Phones:

   iTunes: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/call-of-duty/id733712309?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4

   Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.activision.callofduty.mobile

   Windows Phones: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/call-of-duty/30ba0114-493e-47c5-8b0b-0cdbf9c35281
2. Launch the app. After downloading and installing the app, launch it from your device. Tap its shortcut icon on your phone or tablet’s home screen to open it.
3. Create and name your clan. Once the app is open, scroll down the screen and look for the “Create a Clan” section located at the bottom. Type in the name you want for your clan on the text field provided.

   - Remember, you can’t put special characters in your clan name.
   - Once you’ve entered the name you like, tap on the button labeled “Create a Clan” located just below the text field you typed the clan name on.
   - Once you’ve tapped the “Create a Clan” button and your clan has been created, you’ll be taken straight to the Clan screen. The Clan screen contains all the information about your clan such as Wins, Kill Ratios, Level, Unlocked Achievements, and more.

Hope this helped you!

Comment: this is no longer a valid answer, as the Call of Duty app has been taken down.

Comment: @Timelord64 While yes, this is no longer relevant, it's likely this has been removed all together. Similar to the Army of Two mask maker, the WaW server monitoring, or even the complete removal of the Battlefield: Bad Company 2 servers. I could be mistaken, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Quite possibly, @Ben. I couldnt find any evidence that the feature is still there, myself.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is when you create a clan go to the Call of Duty app and create your logo and what your clan's clan tag is gonna be and then you should be able to invite people.

Answer (score -1):

You Can't Make A Clan Without The App.

[1]https://www.callofduty.com/ghosts/features/clans

Comment: The link you sourced doesnt not actually say that anywhere. Could you perhaps provide a direct quote from where you read it?